# Finding the closest pair of numbers which add to a target number

Tags: python, complexity

This function takes two lists of same length and a target number: the number which is to be summed. The function then returns a list of pairs whose sum is closest to the target number than any other pairs. It also finds the pair whose sum is equal to the target number.

```py
def pair_finder(list1, list2, t):
    list1.sort()
    list2.sort()
    list1.reverse()
    t_low = list1[-1] + list2[0]
    t_high = list1[0] + list2[-1]
    pairs_low = []
    pairs_high = []
    pairs_equal = []
    for i in list1:
        k = 0
        for j in list2:
            if i + j < t:
                if i + j > t_low:
                    pairs_low.clear()
                    t_low = i + j
                    pairs_low.append([i, j])
                elif (i + j == t_low):
                    pairs_low.append([i, j])
            if i + j > t:
                if i + j < t_high:
                    pairs_high.clear()
                    t_high = i + j
                    pairs_high.append([i, j])
                    list2 = list2[k:]
                    break
                elif i + j == t_high:
                    pairs_high.append([i, j])
            if i + j == t:
                pairs_equal.append([i, j])
            k += 1
    pairs = []
    for q in pairs_low:
        pairs.append(q)
    for w in pairs_high:
        pairs.append(w)
    for r in pairs_equal:
        pairs.append(r)
    return pairs

while True:
    try:
        l1 = []
        l2 = []
        li = input("enter the first sequence of numbers by giving exactly one space between numbers:")
        for i in li.split(" "):
            l1.append(int(i))
        lj = input("enter the second sequence of numbers by giving exactly one space between numbers:")
        for j in lj.split(" "):
            l2.append(int(j))
        if len(l1) == len(l2):
            target = int(input("enter the target number: "))
            break
        else:
            print("the length of both sequences should be same!")
            l1 = []
            l2 = []
    except ValueError:
        print("only integer type values are allowed!")
for pair in pair_finder(l1, l2, target):
    print(pair)
```

Example:
Let list 1 be `2 98 63 41 25 27 -51 48 18 54 31 28 55 11` 
 and list 2 be `21 56 87 65 21 12 75 41 33 91 32 15 8 -35` 
and target number be 43 hence the 
pairs `(15, 27),(33, 11),(41, 2),(32, 11),(15, 28),(12, 31)`

Comment: Your code is broken (regarding the correct indentation), also you missed to provide a description what it is purposed to do. Your question is _off-topic_ here, fix these things first before asking for a review please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The code is a C&P error, and can be fixed by anyone - including you. The title includes the description, what more explanation do you need to understand this?

Comment: Yeah you've broke the code again, after I fixed it...

Comment: @Peilonrayz Isn't it the duty of the author to post working code here?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The reason the code is not working is because SE has a non-standard method of displaying code blocks. Causing 'code problems' for people that are new to the system. Please perform a quick browse of meta and you'll see more information.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I think I've manually rolled-back the code to your version.

Answer (score 4):

## Human Computer Interaction

### Prompts

```
        li = input("enter the first sequence of numbers by giving exactly one space between numbers:")
        lj = input("enter the second sequence of numbers by giving exactly one space between numbers:")
```

These are awfully long prompts for the user to enter in a list of values after.  Maybe instructions, and then two short input prompts?

```
        print("Enter two space separated integer number sequences, of the same length.")
        li = input("First sequence:  ")
        lj = input("Second sequence: ")
```

### White-space separators

`li.split(" ")` will separate a string into a number of items separated by exactly one space.  If the user wants to enter a single digit number on one line, and a two digit number on the next, and keep the columns of numbers lined up, they can't use extra spaces.

`.split()`, with no arguments, will split a string into a number of items separated by one or more white-space characters.

```
>>> "     2     3 \t   \n  4 \r  5     ".split()
['2', '3', '4', '5']
```

No hard requirements to use exactly one space.  And leading and trailing spaces are trimmed, too!

## Unexpected Behaviour

```
def pair_finder(list1, list2, t):
    list1.sort()
    list2.sort()
    ...
```

After calling `pair_finder(l1, l2, target)`, you'll find that `l1` and `l2` have been sorted!  The caller probably did not expect that.

Use:

```
def pair_finder(list1, list2, t):
    list1 = sorted(list1)
    list2 = sorted(list2)
    ...
```

The `sorted(...)` function doesn't modify the input list, and it returns a new list.  By assigning those to the original variables, `list1` & `list2` will be sorted, but the caller's `l1` & `l2` lists won't be touched.

## Pythonic Constructs

### Loop like a native

#### List comprehension

```
l1 = []
for i in li.split(" "):
    l1.append(int(i))
```

This is an inefficient construct.  You are creating a list, and then expanding the list one item at a time.

You could create the list all at once, using list comprehension:

```
l1 = [int(i) for i in li.split(" ")]
```

And applying the same operation to every item in a sequence is called a mapping operation, and Python has a built-in `map(func, sequence)` function:

```
l1 = list(map(int, li.split(" ")))
```

Or, combining with the input and using the better space handling:

```
print("Enter two space separated integer number sequences, of the same length.")
l1 = list(map(int, input("First sequence:  ").split()))
l2 = list(map(int, input("Second sequence: ").split()))
```

#### Enumerate

```
        k = 0
        for j in list2:
            ...
            k += 1
```

This should be replaced with:

```
        for k, j in enumerate(list2):
            ...
```

to allow Python to maintain the `k` index while walking through the `list2` items.

### Extending Lists

Adding a list to another list is a `list.extend(...)` operation:

```
pairs = []
for q in pairs_low:
    pairs.append(q)
for w in pairs_high:
    pairs.append(w)
for r in pairs_equal:
    pairs.append(r)
```

Could become simply:

```
pairs = []
pairs.extend(pairs_low)
pairs.extend(pairs_high)
pairs.extend(pairs_equal)
```

### if ... elif

```
        if i + j < t:
            ...
        if i + j > t:
            ...
        if i + j == t:
            ...
```

If the sum is less than `t`, it won't be greater than `t`, or equal to `t`.  And if it is greater than `t`, it won't be equal to `t`.  And if it is not less than or greater than `t`, it can only be equal to `t`.  Why do the extra comparisons?

```
        if i + j < t:
            ...
        elif i + j > t:
            ...
        else:
            ...
```

### PEP-8

#### Unnecessary parenthesis:

```
            elif (i + j == t_low):
```

#### Variable names too short to be meaningful

`li`, `lj`, `l1`, `l1`, `q`, `w`, `r`, `t`

#### Main guard

Mainline code should be protected with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

to allow the file to be imported into another file, for unit tests, etc.

## Algorithmic Improvements

`pair_finder()` starts off by sorting both input lists.  That is an \$O(N \log N)\$ operation.  Then it reverses one of the lists, which is an \$O(N)\$ operation.  And then ...

```
for i in list1:
    ...
    for j in list2:
        ...
```

... which is \$O(N^2)\$!  Right now, this is the time consuming part of the algorithm.  But what are we doing?  We are looking for two numbers which sum to `target`.  Let’s turn that around:

```
for i in list1:
    desired = target - i
    # find “desired” in list2
```

Well, `list2` is sorted, so we can do a binary search to find the `desired` value.

```
for i in list1:
    desired = target - i
    pos = bisect.bisect_left(list2, desired)
    ...
```

The binary search is \$O(\log N)\$, so with the outer loop, the time complexity has dropped to \$O(N \log N)\$, the same as the sorting.

The `desired` value may or may not be in `list2`.  If it is, it is at `list2[pos]`.  Assuming we don’t fall off the start of `list2`, then for the current `i` value, `i+list2[pos-1]` would be the largest sum less than `target`.

Assuming we don’t fall off the end of `list2`, if `list2[pos] == desired`, then the sum `i+list2[pos+1]` will be the smallest sum greater than `target` for the current value of `i`.

```
for i in list1:
    desired = target - i
    pos = bisect.bisect_left(list2, desired)
    if pos < len(list2):
        if list2[pos] == desired:
            # add (i, desired) to pairs_equal
            low, high = pos - 1, pos + 1
        else:
            low, high = pos - 1, pos
        if low >= 0:
            # add (i, list2[low]) to pairs_low, if >= t_low
        if high < len(list2):
            # add (i, list2[high]) to pairs_high, if <= t_high
```

But ... what about duplicates?  If `list2` contains duplicate values, `pos + 1` may not be sufficient to advanced to a value larger than `desired`.  You could use both `bisect_left` and `bisect_right` to find either end of a sequence of multiple `desired` values.  The difference in `right` and `left` would be the count of those values, and you could add `[(i, desired)] * count` to `pairs_equal`.  But you’d also need to do the same for the `pairs_low` and `pairs_high`, which means more binary searching to find those ends.  Or, you could use two `collections.Counter` objects to count occurrences of each value in `list1` and `list2`, and then remove duplicates values from `list1` and `list2`.  Any pairs added would need to be replicated by the product of the respective counts to occur the correct number of times in the result.

Comment: Excellent review. I would stick to the list comprehensions, instead of using `map` for clarity,